# Angular viewChild get offset width

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, viewchild

Angula 11 `// REMARK THIS HAPPENS WITH ALL THE OFFSETS BUT GET THE ID PER EXAMPLE WORKS`

So we have a few `@Viewchilds` of `ElementRefs` that we want to get the `offsetWidth`.

To do that we have the following code:

```
// container is the REF that has the HTML --> #container
@ViewChild('container') containerRef: ElementRef;
...
...
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
const containerOffset: number = this.containerRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
const containerOffset1: number = (this.containerRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement).offsetWidth;
}
```

The problem is that the offsets that we get are 0.

**But** if we do a `console.log(this.containerRef)` it shows perfectly the nativeElement inside and you can see that the offset is different than 0.

Someone can help here please ?

( If possible a solution without using document.querySelector.....)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try and and get offset in setTimeout. Don't rely on console.log, printed value can and will change because it's by referencen (if it's an object). Try instead `console.log(this.containerRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth)` and it will probably be 0 again.

Comment: Okei, my question is why is 0, when it should be bigger like 247 ?

Comment: Because it's probably not fully rendered yet. Make a stackblitz example

Comment: But supposedly, all the elements that has to be accessed with @viewChild, you can access them ASAP on ngAfterInit right ??

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got the width of a parent element view child for my situation. I was able to test this successfully using both "OnInit" and "AfterViewInit".

```
/** Left Column */
@ViewChild('gridLeftColumn', { static: true })
public gridLeftColumn: ElementRef;

const columnWidth: number = (this.gridLeftColumn.nativeElement as HTMLElement).clientWidth;

console.log('Column Width: ', columnWidth); // 760
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.el.nativeElement.clientWidth); //return 0
  }


ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.el.nativeElement.clientWidth); // return 84 (true)
    }, 100);
  }
```

I have a 'Directive' and I found a solution for 'Directives'. Just add a little timeout. Have a nice day!